# free asset library for panda3d

Tags: models, 3d-meshes, assets, panda3d

my game with panda3d is slowly taking form. It's still a mere testcase but I'd like to improve its visual. Since the assets from my previous projects don't fit this game I've used placeholders for the player and enemy models. Now the moving cubes and spheres are starting to annoy me. The game is still very small and I'd rather invest my time in coding instead of modelling.

**Do you know a free asset library for panda3d ? I know I can convert most models to panda's .egg format so any good database would be appreciated.**
Yes, I've already looked at the standard "asset gallery" from the panda3d website.

I'm probably going to redesign everything eventually, nevertheless I'd prefer opensource/free-to-use libraries because I don't want to check every rock and tree if I have to replace it for distribution.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you don't really need an asset library specifically for Panda3D, but any library of free-to-use 3D assets (since you could convert), right?

Comment: that's right. any library would be good. Of course I'd prefer one with panda3d formats but that's not necessary

Comment: As per the [FAQ], questions about where to find free assets are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @TrevorPowell I'm sorry but I didn't check the FAQ. Flagged this question for removal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGameArt.org is a place where free and open source assets are collected and distributed:

http://opengameart.org/

Comment: great that you took the time to contribute an answer to this old question. +1 from me